# Member with no value in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to convert the following C# code to F#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private class DOCINFOA
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string nomeDocumento;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string arquivoSaida;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string tipoDado;
}
```

I'm doing the following:

```
namespace Printer
    module RawPrinterHelper =
            [<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)>]
            type DOCINFOA =
                [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>]
                member this.nomeDocumento
                [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>]
                member this.arquivoSaida
                [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>]
                member this.tipoDado
```

But I receive:
`A type definition requires one or more members`. Can I let these members empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `val` instead of `member`:

```
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)>]
type DOCINFOA =
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>]
    val nomeDocumento : string
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>]
    val arquivoSaida : string
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>]
    val tipoDado : string
```